# Let $q$ be a prime integer. Show that for each $x∈GF(q)$ there exist elements $r$ and $s$ in $GF(q)$ satisfying $x=r^2+s^2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $q$ be a prime integer. Show that for each $x∈GF(q)$ there exist elements $r$ and $s$ in $GF(q)$ satisfying $x=r^2+s^2$.

I'm stuck on this problem. Any solutions or hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This can be proven combinatorially. First, show that if $G$ is a finite group and $A,B$ are nonempty subsets of $G$ then $G=AB$ if $|A|+|B|>|G|$. With this in mind, take $F$ to be a finite field of size $p$ a prime and consider $F$ under addition. Take $A=B$ to be $F^2$. We know this set has cardinality $\dfrac{p+1}2$ (there are $\dfrac{p-1}2$ quadratic residues plus $0$), and $p+1>p$, so under addition we get $F^2+F^2=F$.

Answer (score 0):

Let us fix a non-zero element $x \in GF(q)$ and assume $q>2$. Now consider two sets: $A=\{u^2 \, | \, u \in GF(q)\}$ and $B=\{x-v^2 \, | \, v \in GF(q)\}$. Observe that the first set has cardinality $\frac{q+1}{2}$. Can you show that the second set also has the same cardinality. Note both $A, B \subset GF(q)$. If they were disjoint then they exceed the number of elements in $GF(q)$. So they must have something in common.

If $q=2$, then the result is fairly trivial: $0=0^2+0^2$ and $1=1^2+0^2$.

Comment: @1233dfv since $q>2$ is prime therefore except for the $0$ element every other element will have an additive inverse which is different from the element itself ($u \neq -u$). Since $(u)^2=(-u)^2$, this accounts for $\frac{p-1}{2}$ pairs of elements, now add the $0$ to the list.